# Can't parse mediaqueries with Less PHP

Tags: css, responsive-design, less, media-queries, lessphp

In my Less file I've included some variables that I want to use for mediaqueries in Less:

```
@mobile:      ~"only screen and (max-width: 529px)";
@tablet:      ~"only screen and (min-width: 530px) and (max-width: 949px)";
@desktop:     ~"only screen and (min-width: 950px) and (max-width: 1128px)";
@desktop-xl:  ~"only screen and (min-width: 1129px)";
```

In my css I do something like this for example:

```
@media @desktop{
    .test{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

When I try to parse it with a preprocessor it compiles but when I do it with LessPHP I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'parse error: failed at `@media @desktop {`
```

Comment: I tried it out online in LessPHP 0.4.0 and it compiles fine. See here: [goo.gl/swv8rp](http://goo.gl/swv8rp)

Answer (score 0):

if you put a dummy rule at the top of the file, eg:

```
a {}

@mobile:      ~"only screen and (max-width: 529px)";
@tablet:      ~"only screen and (min-width: 530px) and (max-width: 949px)";
@desktop:     ~"only screen and (min-width: 950px) and (max-width: 1128px)";
@desktop-xl:  ~"only screen and (min-width: 1129px)";

@media @desktop{
    .test{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

It seems to work until the issue is fixed proper.